# Command to create a file with all usernames on server

Tags: linux, file, command

I want to mass run a command on all users on server. The command looks like:

```
command username
```

Is there a way to generate a txt file in / directory with the all usernames on server with output of the file like:

```
command user1
command user2
command user3 
etc.
```

Comment: yes this is possible.

Comment: @PeeHaa how? Please help...

Comment: This will show you how to get all users from the system: http://askubuntu.com/a/410274

Comment: @Gavin /home directory files will be easy.. any way to create a txt file with all folder names of /home?

Comment: Help us help you. Try something. Get stuck. Search the web. try something else. Get stuck again. Google some more. get stuck again. Write a specific answer with your failed attempts and ask the community.

Comment: `who > listOfUsersOnline.txt` play with this research more

Comment: You can get all the usernames by parsing `/etc/passwd`. `awk` is good for this.

Comment: @MichaelMMeskhi who command only shows loggedin users..

Comment: Then run `nmap` to find all ip addresses or usernames logged in on your network. For GUI version get Zenmap

Comment: /etc/passwd. awk seems to have worked for me :) i simply copied usernames and added prefix command to it using online editor ! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

The `getent passwd` command will list all users and some data about them.  I'm not sure if you meant the output of *running* the command should go to the output file, or if you just wanted the text *command user*.  If you want the command output, one way to do it would be

```
getent passwd | cut -f 1 -d : | \
while read user
do  command $user
done > output.txt
```

Tweak if you didn't mean exactly that.  Beware that you also get all the *system accounts* in the list.  If you only want to get “real” user accounts, add a filter on the user id (the third field in the output from `getent`).